# What does accumulate do in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

i'm new to c++, recently I discovered a function called `accumulate()`. I searched over internet about what it is, and read the [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/) tutorial, but couldn't understand what it does

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  int init = 100;
  int numbers[] = {10,20,30};

  cout << accumulate(numbers,numbers+3,init) << "\n";
}
```

Why is the output of the above program 160? I would like to know what the function does and how it works.  Any types help appreciated.

Comment: The link you have posted provides code that's equivalent to calling accumulate. What do you not understand there? That might be the more relevant question.

Comment: well it just accumulates :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can represent the function like this :

```
accumulate(first, last, init)
```

Here `accumulate()` function sums up all the values in the range `[first,last)` that is between `first and (last-1) index`

And here `init` is the initial value of the sum.

The function is similar to the following c++ code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int init = 100;
    int numbers[] = {10,20,30};

    int first = 0, last = 3;
    int sum = init;

    for(int i = first ;i < last ;i++)
      sum = sum + numbers[i];

    cout << sum << "\n";
}
```

So in your example : `init + number[0] + number[1] + number[2] = 100 + 10 + 20 +30 = 160`

One more thing :

```
accumulate(numbers, numbers + 3, init)
```

You may ask, why we are passing numbers in the first parameter rather than 0 ?

The answer is :

Here `accumulate()` function does not know which array you are willing to sum up.
So you need to inform the `starting address` that is address of `numbers[0]` to the function.

And if you want to sum up element between `x position to y-1 position`. You have to write this :

```
accumulate(numbers + x, numbers + y, init)
```

Answer (score 4):

`accumulate` without a special function takes two iterators and returns the sum, your `init` specifies the starting variable.  It's like [fold](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold) or a functional "reduce." The code above gives 160 because it's calculating

```
100 + 10 + 20 + 30
```

`numbers` will be a pointer to the beginning of the array, `numbers+3` is "one-past-end" a typical c++ iterator idiom. It might be clearer if it was written out as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main ()
{
  int init = 100;
  int numbers[] = {10,20,30};

  std::cout << std::accumulate(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), init) << "\n";
}
```

It should be clearer in this example what the range is, the beginning of numbers to the end of numbers.  The `init` variable becomes vital in different cases such as an empty sequence.

You could also specify a different function to use instead of addition, the following will result in `init * 10 * 20 * 30`

```
int mul(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}

int main ()
{
    int init = 100;
    int numbers[] = {10,20,30};

    std::cout << std::accumulate(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), 1, mul) << "\n";
}
```

Though such simple functions are often written as [lambdas](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html)

Comment: Thanks :)
It helped a lot

Comment: But a accepted @Ali's answer, because it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::accumulate
```

is what it's name suggests. It just sums up the whole sequence. In addition you can provide an initial value. In your case initial value is `100`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you read the documentation it says

> Returns the result of accumulating all the values in the range
>   [first,last) to init.

So...

numbers = 10 + 20 + 30 = 60 , init = 100 => 100+60 => 160.

std::accumulate is taking as first iterator, number, and last iterator number+3.